# Accessing valueless implicitly unwrapped optional?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I am curious about the way implicitly unwrapped optionals work, in the Apple reference book - **The Swift Programming Language** it states:

> “If you try to access an implicitly unwrapped optional when it does
>   not contain a value, you will trigger a runtime error. The result is
>   exactly the same as if you place an exclamation mark after a normal
>   optional that does not contain a value.”

If I try and access a valueless optional without an exclamation mark you get an error as stated above.

```
var optionalVar:String?
println("VAR: \(optionalVar!)")
```

If however you try an access an implicitly unwrapped optional that does not contain a value the println outputs `VAR: nil` which is not what is stated above.

```
var implicitOpt:String!
println("VAR: \(implicitOpt)")
```

Can anyone clarify this, is it badly worded docs, me miss understanding, a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thing is that you are not unwrapping the value in this case, but printing unwrapped optional as special type. Weird, I know. Try casting it to normal `String` and it will crash if `nil`:

```
var implicitOpt: String!
println("VAR: \(implicitOpt as String)")
```

The following lines are equal:

```
var implicitOpt: ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String>
var implicitOpt: String!
```

`ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` conforms to `Printable` protocol. So the string interpolation

```
"\(implicitOpt)"
```

will call `description` on `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` instance and not `String` instance. Thats why optional is not unwrapped in this case.

Comment: Yes, it seems that println is a special case - which I guess makes sense as it is primarily a debugging tool

Comment: I guess its string interpolation and not println() to be precise.

Comment: Much appreciated, I just wanted to double check.

Answer (score 0):

When you define it as a implicitly unwrapped optional ,the compiler expects it to be initialised and already holding a value .

If you try to do any operation on the variable it will throw you a run time error .
You can observe that evaluation doesn't throw any runtime error ,it will give you nil (look at the if loop where it is evaluated)

```
var implicitOpt:String!
print("VAR: \(implicitOpt)")


var someValue = 10;

if let x = implicitOpt
{
    someValue=1;
}
else
{
    someValue=2
}


var b = implicitOpt;

b = b + "asdf"

let a = implicitOpt + "asdf"
```